# Issue in rotation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

What i am trying to do is as follows,,
I have a client area, (0,0), (1,0),, and i'm drawing a quadilateral from (-1.5,-1.5) to (1.5,1.5) so that even if we rotate the quad, the client area always stays covered with the quad.
The GlRotated() function rotates the quad using top left point (in this case -1.5,-1.5) as pivot point is there any way that we can rotate the quad using client area's center point (i.e. 0.5,0.5) as the pivot point for rotation of quad ..

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is glTranslate the quad into the client area's center point and then glRotate. Which will effectively leave the quads pivot in the client areas center.